# ¿Cómo convertir un titulo a mayúsculas? (pero solo las palabras no las preposiciones)

Tags: r

Cómo puedo convertir un titulo del tipo: "La ciudad de Picasso", o "castellón de la Plana" a, de forma correcta: "La Cuidad de Picasso" o " Castellón de la PLana".

NO funciona `toTitleCase` pues solo para ingles .

Alguna idea...

si pruebo de estas 2 formas

```
 library(tools)
 unlist(lapply(v, FUN=toTitleCase))
```

Me convierte los "De" y los "La" que no quiero

```
library(tools)
toTitleCase("la ciudad de Picasso")
```

Comment: Bienvenido @Maria a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: De acuerdo a la RAE @Maria a la fecha existen 23 Preposiciones [Preposición](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposici%C3%B3n) en tal sentido, siento decir que la pregunta no incluye ninguna de ellas, a menos claro que se esté preguntando por los [artículos (gramática)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art%C3%ADculo_(gram%C3%A1tica)) en todo caso, si pudieras indicar mediante un listado, las palabras (o letras de una longitud: `a`) que se desean excluir del `TitleCase`, sería estupendo.

Comment: Perdon  no corrrecto preposicones lo que queria decir es conectores del tipo de , la, del , lo que no son palabras.

Comment: *de*, *la* y demás **son** palabras. Y para añadir más dificultad, hay palabras que pueden estar en varias categorías, como Este (punto cardinal, nombre) y este (demostrativo). Cuando hablamos de lenguaje natural, hay muchas cosas que a nosotros nos parecen "naturales" que para un ordenador son muy complicadas.

Answer (score 1):

Las reglas de capitalización son complejas, independientemente del lenguaje ([Reglas del español](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp)), sin embargo, tu idea es trabajar con un `toTitleCase()` cuyo algoritmo es mucho más básico:

- Capitaliza siempre la primer palabra
- No capitaliza ciertas otras que están en una lista

Por supuesto, hace otras cosas importantes, pero básicamente en cuanto a la capitalización el trabajo es el que te comenté. Por lo que transformar el código original a una versión regionalizada es relativamente sencillo:

```
toTitleCaseSpanish <- function (text) 
{
            # Cadenas y patrones que no se capitalizan -------------------------------
            # alone, para extensiones/nombres de archivo y textos que no nos interesa capitalizar
            alone <- c("2D", "3D", "AIC", "BayesX", "GoF", "HTML", "LaTeX", 
                       "MonetDB", "OpenBUGS", "TeX", "U.S.", "U.S.A.", "WinBUGS", 
                       "aka", "et", "al.", "ggplot2", "i.e.", "jar", "jars", 
                       "ncdf", "netCDF", "rgl", "rpart", "xls", "xlsx")


            # either, podemos definir lista de palabras a No capitalizar
            either <- c() # Podemos agregar listas de palabras que no queremos capitalizar
            # Preposiciones y articulos que no capitalizaremos como patrón regex
            lpat <- c('^(a|ante|bajo|cabe|con|contra|de|desde|durante|en|entre|hacia|hasta|le|mediante|para|por|según|sin|so|sobre|tras|versus|vía|el|la|los|las|un|uno|una|unos|unas|al|del)$')
            # ------------------------------------------------------------------------

            titleCase1 <- function(x) {
                do1 <- function(x) {
                    x1 <- substring(x, 1L, 1L)
                    if (nchar(x) >= 3L && x1 %in% c("'", "\"")) 
                        paste0(x1, toupper(substring(x, 2L, 2L)), tolower(substring(x, 
                                                                                    3L)))
                    else paste0(toupper(x1), tolower(substring(x, 2L)))
                }
                if (is.na(x)) 
                    return(NA_character_)
                xx <- .Call("splitString", x, " -/\"()\n")
                alone <- xx %in% c(alone, either)
                alone <- alone | grepl("^'.*'$", xx)
                havecaps <- grepl("^[[:alpha:]].*[[:upper:]]+", xx)
                l <- grepl(lpat, xx, ignore.case = TRUE)
                l[1L] <- FALSE
                ind <- grep("[-:]$", xx)
                ind <- ind[ind + 2L <= length(l)]
                ind <- ind[(xx[ind + 1L] == " ") & grepl("^['[:alnum:]]", 
                                                         xx[ind + 2L])]
                l[ind + 2L] <- FALSE
                ind <- which(xx == "\"")
                ind <- ind[ind + 1L <= length(l)]
                l[ind + 1L] <- FALSE
                xx[l] <- tolower(xx[l])
                keep <- havecaps | l | (nchar(xx) == 1L) | alone
                xx[!keep] <- sapply(xx[!keep], do1)
                paste(xx, collapse = "")
            }
            if (typeof(text) != "character") 
                stop("'text' debe ser un vector de caracteres")
            sapply(text, titleCase1, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
}        

toTitleCaseSpanish(c('la ciudad de Picasso', 'castellón de la Plana'))

[1] "La Ciudad de Picasso"  "Castellón de la Plana"
```

Comment: La pregunta requería bastante trabajo, bien @PatricioMoracho, lo que me ha gustado de la función propuesta, es que permite poner en mayúscula las letras iniciales acentuadas `toTitleCaseSpanish(c('él altísimo'))` Se imprime: `[1] "Él Altísimo"` lo cuál está acorde a la RAE: [Tilde en las mayúsculas](http://www.rae.es/consultas/tilde-en-las-mayusculas)